# Recall score for each sample in multilabel classification

Tags: classification, multilabel-classification, metric

Does it make sense to calculate the recall for each sample in a multilabel classification problem?

Suppose I have 3 data samples, each having its own true set of labels and predicted set of labels.

[image: Sample output]

I want to see the match between the true set of labels and the predicted set of labels. I do not care for the true negatives or false positives in each prediction, so this translates to recall score for me. Programmatically, I would do an AND operation between y_predicted and y_true to get the number of true positives and divide it by the total number of true labels **for each sample**. (in other words, true positives/(true positives+false negatives))

My question is -

> Is calculating recall per sample (not per label), usually done?
>
> Is my thought process correct?

I've seen articles where a single recall is calculated for the whole matrix of y_true and y_predicted or recall is calculated for a single label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This metric is usually referred to as a sample-based or example-based score and can be applied in multi-label cases (to recall and other scores too). You can find a brief explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39420025/12268505).

Scikit learn has an implementation for it (see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.recall_score.html) for recall) when setting  `average='samples'` for `recall_score`:

> `'samples'`: Calculate metrics for each instance, and find their average (only meaningful for multilabel classification where this differs from accuracy_score).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The links were really helpful too. Question - I did look at the sklearn implementation but it says "find their average". Is there a way I can extract just the sample-wise recall without calculating the average?

Comment: @AishwaryaAR Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is no implementation of that in scikit learn (unless you apply `recall_score` on each example but I'd rather implement it myself then).